# Google Scripts Triggers - wrong timezone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

When I manually add  a new trigger it will be created in a different timezone compared to the Spreadsheet Settings as well to the Project Properties. How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might wish to checkout this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=867).

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me too. The only way to get around it is to install the trigger programmatically.

```
function addTrigger() {
  // main() will be called weekly on Monday at 16:00 in the specified time zone
  var everyWeek = ScriptApp.newTrigger("main")
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(1)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
      .atHour(16)
      .create();
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358457/2701899

Answer (score 0):

I live in GMT-7 but we're on Daylight Saving Time now so we're really on GMT-6 time.  I set up a trigger to fire off at 20:31 and at 20:31:03 it wrote the time into a file.  I was watch the Google Drive Directory and saw the Last Modified time change on the file and when I checked the file sure enough it agreed with the GMT-6 time zone time.

So I am not seeing the problem myself.  If your seeing a time later by one hour perhaps your not taking into account Daylight Savings Time.

I just did it again and sure enough it's working okay.