# Time Trigger in Google Apps Script on date and time

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

In Google apps script it is possible to create timetrigger on a specific date and time. Excactly on that moment the trigger fires. Great!

The question is what is the code in apps script of this trigger?

Following code will fire somewhere between 9:00 and 10

```
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("function")
.timeBased()
.onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
.atHour(9)
.create();
```

Following code fires somewhere between 9:00 and 10 too.

```
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("function")
.timeBased()
.onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
.atHour(9)
.nearMinute(12)
.create();
```

.atMinute does not exist in apps script.

So who knows the code of the manual trigger on specific date and time?

Comment: use `at` as per answer below if specific date and time. if you want it to trigger regularly at specific time, then you'd have to try this [approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vob6Qy01-_Y&ab_channel=DavidWeiss)

Comment: Yes I was looking for this smart solution. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: Next time, clarify your post. It says specific data and time but you only want the specific time regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want it to be on a specific date and time, you need to use `at` instead.

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  Logger.log(new Date());
}

function trigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  // month starts at 0 (e.g. Jan - 0, Feb - 1, etc)
  .at(new Date(2022, 1, 19, 0, 15))
  .create();
}
```

#### Trigger created:

[image: trigger]

Comment: Octiva is this OK now?

Comment: Hi @user3887038, can you try and show the trigger created in the trigger page after you execute the script that creates the trigger?

Comment: See editor in spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qg8QeRCt77cMecLVtlso_QC9YGkZb1ZDQNuM_t0Gj2I/edit#gid=0, This trigger did not fire yet. It should fire almost 2 hours ago. It will fired after about 4 hours from now because the Timezone of new Date is default in GMT-5 (I am in GMT+1). I tried already when I save the trigger in the trigger page he fired at the correct time. Please advise.

Comment: You set it to Feb 25 2022 5:05. Note that month starts at 0 for date object. That means Jan 25 is `new Date(2022, 0, 25, 17, 05)` while your `new Date(2022, 1, 25, 17, 05)` means Feb 25. @user3887038, it has been added as comment on the code itself. `// month starts at 0 (e.g. Jan - 0, Feb - 1, etc)`

Comment: Please confirm if this solves your issue @user3887038

Comment: Sorry but with month as 0 same problem. (tried many times before with 0). The trigger does not fire at that time but 6 hours later. If your experience is that such a trigger fires at the right time what is wrong in settings of my spreadsheet. Please improve in editor of my sheet.

Comment: What I would recommend is that you try it on a new sheet and editor. I don't see any issues with yours. maybe the timezone matters? Can you try and see the [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358457/17842569) on this one.

Comment: Already did on several new sheets with same result. If you do so have you the same problem? Is in your editor new Date not in GMT+5? You are living in GMT+8, so the difference is 13 hours. So please tell me what happens if you use the same script.

Comment: it works specifically on the time I trigger it. See https://ibb.co/R7ZYSPv. I used `.at(new Date(2022, 0, 27, 0, 25))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241439/discussion-between-rob-and-octavia-sima).