# Google Apps Script Trigger Timezone Will Not Change

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timezone

I am trying to set up a trigger in a Google Apps Script project that runs once per day at the same time. To avoid issues with daylight savings, I set the timezone for the spreadsheet to be GMT-0 and I set it as GMT-0 under the project settings for the Apps Script project. Nevertheless, this is what I am presented with when I create a trigger:

[image: Timezone that triggers will not change from (GMT-6)]

GMT-6. This is my actual timezone. I saw other people were having issues with this and so I tried the solution from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358457/6269215) It did not work. This is the exact code I used:

```
function addTrigger() {
  // main() will be called weekly on Monday at 16:00 in the specified time zone
  var everyWeek = ScriptApp.newTrigger("setTrigger")
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(1)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .inTimezone("Etc/UTC")
      .atHour(16)
      .create();
}
```

All this did was create a trigger at 16:00 in GMT-6. It completely ignored the `.inTimezone("Etc/UTC")`.

I have tried using a VPN to spoof my location and see if that allows the timezone to change from GMT-6, it didn't. Is there some place in my Google account that this is pulling from and getting GMT-6? I checked in my Google Calandar and that had GMT-0 as my default, it made no difference.

When I get the current date in a script I get a date and time in GMT-0. So there is bascially a constant 6 hour offset between what I do in a script and when the triggers operate. It seems that everything follows GMT-0 except the triggers which are somehow holding onto GMT-6.

Please someone just tell me how I can change the timezone for triggers. I have wasted far too much time on such a stupid issue.

My `appsscript.json` file looks like the following:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Etc/UTC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried another [Joda.org](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) Time Zone for GMT + 00 ? Such as `UTC`, `Europe/London` or `Etc/GMT`? [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#intimezonetimezone)

Comment: @Emel In the code snippet above? Yes, I've tried multiple Joda timezones and none of them have had any effect.

Comment: 1.Have you tried changing your locale/language settings in Google? https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info 2.Can you show your appscript.json file?

Comment: @TheMaster I don't see anything in that page about my location. My language is set as English (United States), but I don't see how that would affect my timezone. I have updated my question to include the `appsscript.json` file.

Comment: What returns `Session.getScriptTimeZone()`?

Comment: @Emel `Etc/UTC`

Comment: Can you confirm how you verified that "All this did was create a trigger at 16:00 in GMT-6"?  Did you wait for it to run and it indeed ran at that hour?  Or you just see it listed as such in the project triggers page?  My experience has been consistent with theMaster's answer, that the trigger runs at the correct time when set from the script, but the triggers page always displays that time incorrectly, as if it were in the local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

> All this did was create a trigger at 16:00 in GMT-6. It completely ignored the .inTimezone("Etc/UTC").

I believe this is inaccurate. After testing, I found that a trigger was created at 16:00 in UTC.  Even though the UI dashboard may still show `GMT-6` the actual trigger is created in the specified timezone. I believe this is just a UI bug.

Answer (score 0):

If the script project is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to a spreadsheet, it may be easiest to use the timezone of the spreadsheet, because it is easy to check and set in the spreadsheet's **File > Settings**. To use the spreadsheet's timezone, replace `'Etc/UTC'` with `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`.

To make the code easier to read, set the timezone as the last thing before `.create()`, like this:

```
function addTrigger() {
  const timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const weeklyTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunctionToRunWeekly')
      .timeBased()
      .everyWeeks(1)
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(16)
      .inTimezone(timezone)
      .create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the way you are formatting your trigger?

This is something that I would do when creating one.

```
function setUpTrigger() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('setTrigger')
  .timeBased()
  .everyWeeks(1)
  .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
  .atHour(16)
  .nearMinute(0)
  .inTimezone('Etc/UTC')
  .create();
}

function setTrigger() {
  //Your stuff that happens every monday at 1600
}
```

Also note that if you use atHour the time would be anytime from 1600-1700.

If you include something like nearMinute(0) there would be a 15 minutes +/- interval for the trigger to run as well.